# Could someone explain me the top x% so much used in the USA

Tags: discussion, profile-page, community

I guess is very common there, I'm not sure how common is it in other parts of the world, but I don't quite get what that percent number represent? Or hot to read it?

Less is better I assume from [Jon Skeet profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the top n users are those n users that have the most reputation. Then consequently the top n% users are those `(n * user_count) / 100` users who have the most reputation. And if your profile reads you're in the top n% that means you're one of those users.

And yes, lower numbers are better as being one of the top 10 users is clearly better than only being one of the top 1000 users (though obviously any member of the top 10 is also in the top 1000).

Comment: Makes sense. Although every time I see the number% I counterintuitive think that more is better. How common is using this outside USA BTW?

Comment: @Oscar: Well I'm not from the USA and I often see statistics of the form "The x% richest people of country Y have z% of the money", so it doesn't seem to be too uncommon (and clearly when being in the richest x%, smaller x are better as well).