# Why doesn't "Top n % this year" ever appear?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

According to the accepted answer by Rick Sladkey to the question [Why does the "top X%" in my profile change frequently between week/month/all time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92328/why-does-the-top-x-in-my-profile-change-frequently-between-week-month-all-tim) your best overall percentage ranking in the league is displayed on your profile.

> The metric reported on your profile under the big score is your best overall percentage ranking in the leagues over the most recent time periods that are collected and reported.
>   To see how you fare in the other categories just check the:
>
> - week
> - month
> - quarter
> - year
> - all-time

However I noticed that for at least one user, Ernest Friedman-Hill, this doesn't work if the best overall percentage is year.

His profile lists him as "top 2% overall", but if you check on the user leagues he's ranked 145 for the year. The tool tip for the cumulative users with a rep change of +250 for the year is 31,602. Percentage for the year for Ernest is (145/31,602) * 100 = 0.46%, which is better than 2%.

I've also noticed I've never seen Top n% this year for anyone else.

So is my understanding of how to calculate top n% wrong or is Rick Sladkey's answer mostly correct?

[image]

My apologies to Ernest for picking on you.

Comment: Why is 0.46% better than 2.00%?

Comment: see [Could someone explain me the top x% so much used in the USA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81615/could-someone-explain-me-the-top-x-so-much-used-in-the-usa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, thanks for reporting this.  It's <s>probably</s> *definitely* happening because it wasn't in a list of things it needed to be in...

This will be fixed in the next build, it'll just start appearing where appropriate.

Comment: `new List<LeagueInterval> { Week, Month, Quarter, AllTime }`...guess what's missing? :)

Comment: @DavidFullerton I was pretty surprised by the number of people that now say "this year" including 3 of the top 5 overall.